# Getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined` when socket.io is included via webpack

Tags: javascript, socket.io, webpack-4

I'm using webpack4 to bundle my vendor files. Everything works well and I included the bundle.js file on my webpage. 
But the issue is that I can't access the socket.io from my js file. Am getting an error in the console as below:

> main.js:276 Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined
>       at main.js:276

***Here is my socket.io code***

```
var socket = io().connect();
socket.on('logout', function (data) {
    if (data.includes(userId))
        window.location.href = '/auth/signout';
});
```

***Here is my webpack.config.js file***

```
const path = require('path');
const glob = require('glob');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    target: "web",
    entry: {
        page1: glob.sync('./public/js/vendor/*.js')
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./public/build"),
        filename: "bundle.js",
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            "window.jQuery": 'jquery',
        })
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {test: /modernizr/, loader: 'imports-loader?this=>window!exports-loader?window.Modernizr'},
            {test: path.resolve(__dirname, './public/js/vendor/wow.min.js'), loader: 'imports-loader?this=>window!exports-loader?window.WOW'}
            ]
    },
    resolve: {
        modules: [
            path.resolve(__dirname, "./public/js/vendor")
        ]
    },
    externals: {
        jquery: 'jQuery',
        jspdf: 'jspdf',
        moment: 'moment',
        $: 'jQuery'
    },
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
};
```

I don't know what am doing here. I searched a lot but not find anything helpful! 
Thanks

Comment: Are you missing initialization of *io* ?
```
const io = require('socket.io')(app);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing initialization of *io* ?

```
const io = require('socket.io')(app);
```

Comment: I'm using socket.io on the client side. My code works well before am introducing webpack.

Comment: I already check it out. It's not worked for me. I'm using front-end js. Not any frameworks like React/Angular.

Comment: sorry I can't share my repo